# Bootstrap nav on hover flicker issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and I am changing the color of the link on hover.

The problem is when I hover there is a slight flicker which causes the navbar height to change. Any leads on how to fix it.

[Here is the demo](http://bootply.com/112898)

Answer (score 0):

Link has `border-bottom: 4px solid white;` when you hover over it.
Give your normal `li` the same border.

```
.navbar .nav>li {
float: left;
border-bottom: 4px solid;
}
```